ASP.Net Razor C# Processing variables included from Database
I have a asp.net Core razor web application that is compiled dynamically based on database configurations. I am experiencing an issue when accessing variables in what I would call a "second level" scenario.
Consider the following page markup
<p>@model.MyPropertyOnTheModel</p>

If the value of MyPropertyOnTheModel is a plain string for example "Hello World" you will get the expected output of
<p>Hello World</p>

But in my case ( and this is just a silly example ) the value of MyPropertyOnTheModel is actually "Hello @User.Identity.Name". Which results in the output of
<p>Hello @User.Identity.Name</p>

Which is obviously undesirable. I want it to be
<p>Hello somebody@someemail.com</p>

My views are all loaded from the DB (DbFileProvider) and then are dynamically compiled and don't get re-compiled unless a change occurs. I want to keep this in tact as it is very fast ( once warmed up ) and if I start going down the road of string parsing / streams / dynamic evaluation I'm worried it may become a bit slow as it will essentially "re-evaluate" that string on each request. Bear in mind this is a stupid example just to display my point.
I can imagine in the bowels of the compiled view there sits a line of code that looks like .writeLine("<p>Hello @User.Identity.Name</p>") as it is assuming it to be a string literal. But there must be a smart way to get the compiler to recognize the razor syntax and treat it as such.
Has anybody come across this issue and solved it?

Hello @model.MyEmailAddress
When you using Identity have you imported the required namespaces for it to identity @User.Identity.Name ?
